# Payfort sdk and web view for ios

Tags: ios, xcode, payfort

Apple refused my applicational because PAYFORT SDK use web view. 
How can I handle it?
Any one faced this issue before?

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

Comment: i had the same issue with payfort, and unfortunately they are not follow the latest guidelines, so i will wait after emailing them. to solve this issue

Comment: Payfort replies to me and they are sure that they are using ukwebview , I don’t know what should I do

Comment: Yes, they have an update on the sdk just download the latest version 2.2, they fix it, but you have to update xcode after update the sdk if u didn’t update it before

Comment: Thanx a lot, yes they mailed us with the latest update version

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView in your app.

Apple will no longer accept new apps using UIWebView as of April 2020. Please refer the below document.
https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12232019b

Comment: How to do that and I don’t have the access to payfort sdk. Is there a way to do it from my Xcode project ?!